# socket chat application room issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io

I am creating a chatapp with node.js express and react. The application working and sending message all users but when i try send message to specific room, it's not working.
The backend
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

```
socket.on('login', (data) => {
    socket.join("room1");
})

socket.on('sendMessage', (data) => {

    socket.emit('messageResponse', data); // **this is working**

    socket.to("room1").emit('messageResponse', data); // **this is not working**
})
```

})

Comment: I don't understand your problem, with your current code the line `socket.emit('messageResponse', data);` should only send the message back to only one socket, the one that connected to `io.on('connection'`. It shouldn't send a message to all sockets, unless there are parts of code that you didn't include in the question

Comment: My problem is this, when i try to emit data from backend like socket.to(room).emit(event,data) it's not working. But if i send directyly data without "to(room)" like socket.emit(event,data), it is working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rooms in socket.io. How to send messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822753/rooms-in-socket-io-how-to-send-messages)

Comment: You can see an exemple of the right syntax in the proposition of duplicate: the syntax is `io.to("room1").emit('messageResponse', data);`. The variable `socket` here represents a specific socket, to send a message to a room you do it with the global `io` variable

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: can you be more precise? What happened? error messages? no error but no message?

Comment: io.to("room1").emit('messageResponse', data); this is also not working.

Comment: Yes there is no error message

Comment: Then you should add a minimal reproducible exemple, many things can go wrong in codes you didn't share (for example did you verify the `'login'` message has been received by server and the socket has successfully joined the room?). You should show how you test your script (clients connexion to socket, etc)

Comment: User doesn't need to be login. This is a basic chat app. I do same on the document or videos from youtube :) But my app is not working. Client side => useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("messageResponse", (data) => {
      setMessageList((prev) => [...prev, data]);
    });
  }, [socket]);

Comment: Please add the code to the question itself, it's hard to read in comments. From your code the client must send a `'login'` message to the socket to join `'room1'`. If this message is never sent by the client through the socket, the server actually never adds the socket to the room, and so the client never receives the message you send to the room

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem. My problem was about socket.io-client. I was sending socket as a prop to other components like `<Chat username={username} room={room} socket={socket} />`. When i create socket.js file in some directory and import in the pages, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead

```
socket.in("room1").emit('messageResponse', data);
```

Please send the code of the receiving end for more insight.

Comment: already tried this and not working.

Comment: Can you send the code for the side you are receiving the data?

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("messageResponse", (data) => {
      setMessageList((prev) => [...prev, data]);
    });
  }, [socket]);

Comment: remove the tracking dependency on useEffect.  Make it useEffect(()=>{  //your code })